# Updating CollectionView inside tableview cells dynamically

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I am getting Lists of Headers say 
`headersArray = ["header1","header2","header3"]` from one api 
from second api by using per header name , I will get data which I have to show in tableView cells that have collectionView in it 
now I want to reload data in that collection

I had updated my tableView with headers and setup collectionView cells

```
func updateCollection(){
    for i in 0...categoriesArray.count - 1 { 
        CategoryService.fetchSubCategoriesAPI(row: i, category: categoriesArray[i]) {[weak self] (result, rowUpdated) in
            print(rowUpdated)
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

**it should be like**

`header1
cat 1 , cat 2 , cat 3`

`header2
cat 1, cat 2`

`header 3
cat 1, cat 2 , cat 3, cat 4`

in cell for row at i have updated my collectionView using collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: Please add some more code for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Please make sure collectionViewDelegate and DataSource methods are connected to collectionView.